# Copy EnvVar string to char[] variable

Tags: file, capl

I have a panel to select a text file and read its content. I store the name in an EnVar and I use it as a parameter to open a text file. I declared the envvar in the database as String.

```
on envVar addFile
{
   if(@this == 1)
   {
      openFileRead(@dataSTYFile, 0)
   }
}
```

This has the next error:

> dataSTYFile must have type integer or float.

When I change the envvar to Integer, the parameters do not match with the function openFileRead. I have tried also copying the value of the envvar using strncpy but the results are the same. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I came with a good solution. I cannot use StringCons = @EnvVarConst since EnvVarConst is not a String type at all. So I used getValue() to get the string value stored in the EnvVar.

```
getValue(dataSTYFile, myCharVar);
```

getValue() takes the value of the EnvVar at the first parameter and assign it to the second parameter.